# How to get value of bean property when property name itself is a dynamic variable

Tags: jsp, properties, javabeans, el, jspx

I'm trying to write a custom JSPX tag that reads the value of a given bean property from each object in a given list, with the name of that property passed to the tag as a JSP attribute. The tag would look something like this:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
        version="2.0">
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <jsp:directive.attribute name="items" type="java.lang.Iterable"
        required="true" description="The items whose properties are to be read"
        rtexprvalue="true"/>
    <jsp:directive.attribute name="propertyName" type="java.lang.String"
        required="true" description="The name of the bean property to read"
        rtexprvalue="true"/>

    <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
        <!-- This is the bit that doesn't work -->
        <jsp:getProperty name="item" property="${propertyName}" />
    </c:forEach>

</jsp:root>
```

The problem is that the `property` attribute of the `jsp:getProperty` tag doesn't seem to accept an expression, only a literal value. So this would work, but is no use to me (as I don't know the property name until runtime):

```
<jsp:getProperty name="item" property="firstName" />
```

The error I get is:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
PWC6054: Cannot find any information on property '${propertyName}' in
a bean of type 'com.example.FooBar'
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to use dynamic property names, use the brace notation.

```xml
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
    ${item[propertyName]}
</c:forEach>
```

#### See also:

- [Jakarta EE Tutorial - Expression Language - Referencing Object Properties](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#referencing-object-properties-or-collection-elements)
- [Jakarta EE Tutorial - Expression Language - Examples of EL Expressions](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#examples-of-el-expressions)

Comment: @BalusC Thank you very much... I was struggling in accessing properties using jsp:getProperty but not its working fine... :-)